# Determining most queried columns in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in the process of attempting to document a SQL Server database that contains 180 tables and over 17,000 columns. My main focus would be on the tables and the columns in those tables that are most popular (which tables/column are queried the most, how many views contain the same columns) the objective here is to create a data dictionary that can be used throughout the company.

How could I best accomplish this if at all possible?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: good catch thank you

Comment: I see a description but no question.

Comment: sql2016+ = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That sounds like there are some design issues in your database. 180 tables with 17,000 columns is an average of more than 94 columns per table.

Answer (score 0):

The most beautiful option is to create a .chm file. ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help))

Next option which comes to mind: create table with fields like tablename, column, description. And make a query:

```
SELECT * FROM libTable
WHERE tablename = 'anytable'
```

17000 rows doesn't seem like a large amount of storage for such data ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could get most executed queries like this

```
select *
from   sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
  cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) b 
order by execution_count desc
```

These are the most executed queries, not the slowest.
If you want the slowest just change the order by to

```
order by total_worker_time / execution_count desc
```

how to show results in nice way is up to you, the answer of @bukse might help with that